# Assigning a custom post type to a custom page

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, admin-menu

I'm trying to add a custom post type to a custom page called slides (admin.php?page=slides) and it doesn't want to work. This is my first attempt at a technical plugin using pages. The custom page gets created fine however when I include the function to generate the custom post type it doesn't load into the view. My page generation code is:

```
add_submenu_page('slideroo', 
    'Slides', 'Slides', 'manage_options', 
    'sliderama-slides', 'slides_page');
```

And my function to register the post type is:

```
function slides_page()
 {
$labels = array(
    'name' =&gt; _x('My Slides', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' =&gt; _x('Slide Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' =&gt; _x('Add New', 'Slide item'),
    'add_new_item' =&gt; __('Add New Slide Item'),
    'edit_item' =&gt; __('Edit Slide Item'),
    'new_item' =&gt; __('New Slide Item'),
    'view_item' =&gt; __('View Slide Item'),
    'search_items' =&gt; __('Search Slide'),
    'not_found' =&gt;  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' =&gt; __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' =&gt; ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' =&gt; $labels,
    'public' =&gt; true,
    'publicly_queryable' =&gt; true,
    'show_ui' =&gt; true,
    'query_var' =&gt; true,
    'menu_icon' =&gt; null,
    'rewrite' =&gt; true,
    'capability_type' =&gt; 'post',
    'hierarchical' =&gt; false,
    'menu_position' =&gt; null,
    'supports' =&gt; array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'slideroo' , $args );
```

Thanks

Comment: Please someone correct me if I am wrong. You can't add a custom post type to a page. I think you may not be explaining yourself quite right.

Comment: Second the first comment.  Not clear on exactly what you are trying to do.  I think it is safe to assume ( based on admin.php?page=slides) that you are having trouble creating the WP Admin menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstand the purpose of add_submenu_page and it's callback function.

If you take a look at Wordpress Codex you will see that the purpose of this function , in your case the slides_page function, is to output the content of the page. ie output HTML code etc

```
$function
(callback) (optional) The function to be called to output the content for this page.
Default:
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

You have to separate the presentation from the logic of your plugin.

You can register your custom posts when the user activates the plugin using the `register_activation_hook` hook.

Comment: Thanks, Had overthought the process. Have created a custom post type and created submenu pages to said post type.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:
Create a template for your custom page 'slides.' Inside of that template, use WP_Query to call in your custom post type. Like so:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'slideroo', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
  // Posts format here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Not sure if that's what you really need.